# compile error "The method is undefined for the type"

Tags: java, arrays, class

Trying to solve this compile error, but cant understand why it is showing.
In one class (class - Account) i defined an array of Products:

```
private Product[] productList;          //List of products for a customer
```

and wrote this function:

```
//Prints all products entered to the account
public void printAllProducts()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i<this.productCounter)
    {
        printProduct(this.productList[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

also, of course wrote a printAllProduct function in class Account:

```
//print specific product
public void printProduct(Product printMe)
{
    System.out.println("in printProduct");
}
```

But keep getting an compile error:

```
The method printProduct(Product) is undefined for the type Account
```

this is the complete "Account" class:

```
package Q2;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] x;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello");
        System.out.println("-------------------------");

        System.out.print("Enter the amount the Cashier start with or 0 for Zero amount to start with: ");
        int startAmount = scan.nextInt();

        Cashier newCashier; //create new cashier object with or without a start amount
        if (startAmount>0)
        {
            newCashier = new Cashier(startAmount);
        }
        else
        { 
            newCashier = new Cashier();
        }

        System.out.print("Enter new Customer name: "); //create a new customer
        String name = scan.next();
        Account newAccount = new Account(name);

        int hasMore = 1; // New customer has at least 1 product, when hasMore = 0 purchase has finish and customer has no more products to buy
        do
        {
            newAccount.addNewProduct();

            //checking if there are more products for this customer
            System.out.println("Enter 1 if the customer has another product or 0 to finish purchase");
            hasMore = scan.nextInt();
        } while (hasMore!=0);


        newAccount.printAllProducts(); //Check method that prints all products for a customer


    }
}
```

this is the complete "Product" class:

```
package Q2;

import java.util.Scanner;

//Class for product
public class Product 
{
    private String name;            //name of a product 
    private int amount;             //amount from a given product
    private int price;              //price of a given product

    public Product()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the name of the product: "); //Start getting details about new product
        this.name = scan.next();
        System.out.print("Enter the amount: ");
        this.amount = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the price: ");
        this.price  = scan.nextInt();
    }


    //print specific product
    public void printProduct(Product printMe)
    {
        System.out.println("in PrintMe");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give here your complete code, because it's not clear how many classes and methods you have.....

Comment: Please write complete class. You may nest methods incorrectly.

Comment: i think you have written printProduct(Product) in Product class and trying to call it printProduct(this.productList[i]) from Account class that is the reason the compiler is giving error. Trying shifting printProduct(Product) to Account class. Anyways its a guess unless you upload your test code

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself:

> of course wrote a printAllProduct function **in class Product**

So you need to use

```
Product product = this.productList[i];
product.printProduct(this.productList[i]);
```

That shows a design problem. Why would the method `printProduct()`, in class Product, take another Product as argument? It should simply be

```
Product product = this.productList[i];
product.print();
```

And the `print()` method would print the product on which it's called (i.e. `this`).

Comment: And `printProduct()` (without the "All" inside, is in class Product). Read your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay
I succeed fixing it and now it works,
I really didn't understand why it didn't worked the first way I wrote.
Why I cant start a function only with parameter in the () and have to work on "this."

This is the code that works:

```
//Prints all products entered to the account
public void printAllProducts()
{
    int i = 0;
    Product ProductToPrint;
    do
    {
        ProductToPrint = this.productList[i];
        ProductToPrint.printProduct(); 
        i++;
    }while (i<this.productCounter);
}
```